# Ruby on Rails: How do I pass variables with observer_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
    <%= observe_field :tb_search, 
    :frequency=>0.5, :update=>'reports',
    :url=>{
        :action=>'filter_reports',
        :only_path=>false,
        :user=>@user.id},
    :with=>"'search='+encodeURIComponent(value)" %>
```

but on the controller side, params[:user] is nil.
I did a

```
    puts "NTHDEONUTHDOEDEUU#{params[:user].nil?}||"
```

in the responding method in controller to prove to myself that it was nil.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this helper I believe you need to pass all params through the `:with` option. Something like:

```
<%= observe_field :tb_search, 
    :frequency=>0.5, :update=>'reports',
    :url=>{
      :action=>'filter_reports',
      :only_path=>false},
    :with=>"'search='+encodeURIComponent(value)+'&user='#{@user.id}"
```

Comment: as it turns out, I was updating the wrong html content, now my problem is that nothing is filtered